# What vertex shader code should be used for a pixel shader used for simple 2D SpriteBatch drawing in XNA?

Tags: silverlight, xna, shader

### Preface

First of all, why is a **vertex shader** required for a `SilverlightEffect` (.slfx file) in Silverlight 5? I'm trying to port a simple 2D XNA game to Silverlight 5 RC, and I would like to use a basic **pixel shader**. This shader works great in XNA for Windows and Xbox, but I can't get it to compile with Silverlight as a SilverlightEffect.

The [MS blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2011/10/04/silverlight-toolkit-september-2011-for-silverlight-5-what-s-new.aspx) for the Silverlight Toolkit says that "there is no difference between .slfx and .fx", but apparently this isn't quite true -- or at least SpriteBatch is working some magic for us in "regular XNA", and it isn't in "Silverlight XNA".

If I try to directly copy my pixel shader file into a Silverlight project (and change it to the supported "Effect - Silverlight" importer/processor), when I try to compile I see the following error message:

```
Invalid effect file. Unable to find vertex shader in pass "P0"
```

Indeed, there isn't a vertex shader in my pixel shader file. I haven't needed one with my other 2D XNA apps since I'm just doing basic SpriteBatch drawing.

I tried adding a vertex shader to my shader file, using [Remi Gillig's comment on this Shawn Hargreaves blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) for guidance, but it doesn't quite work. The shader file successfully compiles, and I see some semblance of my game on screen, but it's tiny, twisted, repeated, and all jumbled up. So clearly something's not quite right.

---

### The Real Question

So that brings me to my real question: Since a vertex shader is required, **is there a basic vertex shader function that works for simple 2D SpriteBatch drawing?**

And if the vertex shader requires world/view/project matricies as parameters, **what values am I supposed to use for a 2D game?**

Can any shader pros help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XNA, `SpriteBatch` is providing its own vertex shader. Because there is no `SpriteBatch` in Silverlight 5, you have to provide your own.

You may want to look at [the source code](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/stock_effects) for the shader that `SpriteBatch` uses (it's in `SpriteEffect.fx`). Here is its vertex shader, it's pretty simple:

```
void SpriteVertexShader(inout float4 color    : COLOR0,
                        inout float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0,
                        inout float4 position : SV_Position)
{
    position = mul(position, MatrixTransform);
}
```

So now you just need the input position and the transformation matrix (and the texture co-ordinates, but those are fairly simple).

The same [blog post you linked](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx), towards the end, tells you how to set up the matrix ([also here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18450/how-do-i-align-the-matrix-used-in-spritebatch-and-the-matrix-used-in-basiceffect/18511#18511)). Here it is again:

```
Matrix projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, viewport.Width, viewport.Height, 0, 0, 1);
Matrix halfPixelOffset = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0);
Matrix transformation = halfPixelOffset * projection;
```

(Note: I'm not sure if Silverlight actually requires the half-pixel offset to maintain texel alignment ([ref](http://drilian.com/2008/11/25/understanding-half-pixel-and-half-texel-offsets/)). It probably does.)

The tricky bit is that the positioning of the sprite is done outside of the shader, on the CPU. Here's the order of what `SpriteBatch` does:

- Start with four vertices in a rectangle, with (0,0) being the top-left and the texture's (width,height) as the bottom right
- Translate backwards by origin
- Scale
- Rotate
- Translate by position

This places the sprite vertices in "client space", and then the transformation matrix transforms those vertices from client space into projection space (which is used for drawing).

I've got a highly-inlined version of this transformation in [ExEn](http://andrewrussell.net/exen/) (`SpriteBatch.InternalDraw` in `SpriteBatchOpenGL.cs`) that you could easily adapt for your use.

Comment: **Thank you** for this incredibly thorough answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. Problem solved! Also: ExEn is *very* intriguing. I'll definitely be checking it out. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, and I just wanted to make one small note. As of Silverlight 5 (Toolkit), it looks like Silverlight actually *does* have a SpriteBatch. Apparently it just doesn't provide its own vertex shader. "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.dll assembly will add the following classes to Silverlight 5: ContentManager, Model, SpriteFont and SpriteBatch", from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2011/10/04/silverlight-toolkit-september-2011-for-silverlight-5-what-s-new.aspx

Comment: Ah - excellent, thanks for the heads up. I wasn't aware of the Toolkit. Seems that fills in a lot of the blanks in SL5's XNA implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question today and I want to add that you can do all of the calculations in the vertex shader itself:

```
float2 Viewport; //Set to viewport size from application code

void SpriteVertexShader(inout float4 color    : COLOR0,
                       inout float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0,
                       inout float4 position : POSITION0)
{
   // Half pixel offset for correct texel centering.
   position.xy -= 0.5;
   // Viewport adjustment.
   position.xy = position.xy / Viewport;
   position.xy *= float2(2, -2);
   position.xy -= float2(1, -1);
}
```

(I didn't write this, credit goes to the comments in the [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) mensioned above)