# Silverlight 5 - Drawing Sprites

Tags: silverlight, xna, silverlight-5.0

I know this may be a bit early, but I've just started a new game in silverlight, and thought it would be neat to start it in Silverlight 5.  The only problem is, I can not find -anything- online about drawing 2D. The very limited info out there is only for 3D.  Does anyone have any links to examples, tutorials, or even just documentation that would help me with this?  Would perhaps waiting a few weeks/months do me any good with google results?

Or am I totally wrong in my thinking, is silverlight 5 actually no more efficient at drawing 2D than Version 4?  (or the slight benefit is not worth the complexity of drawing polygons in 3D space, and painting sprites on them)

Comment: take a look [here](http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/creatinga2dsprite/CreatingA2DSprite.shtml) is not specific about silverlight but since the 3D support of silverlight 5 is provided by XNA, maybe is the same or similar... look for windows phone xna resources too (again im not sure if SL5 implement all the XNA features of the phone but the basics should be the same)

Comment: Thanks Leo :)  I've developed with XNA before, I just didn't know the differences etc for silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `SpriteBatch` in Silverlight 3 (or newer), use [ExEn](http://andrewrussell.net/exen/). It uses an elegant hack to get hardware accelerated immediate-mode sprite rendering using Silverlight's retained-mode graphics system.

(You could also use the retained-mode graphics system directly - but that is kind of painful for game development.)

If you want `SpriteBatch` in Silverlight 5, try the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/), which adds an implementation of XNA's `SpriteBatch` (and other handy things) on top of the subset of the XNA API that Silverlight 5 provides.

Check out [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191152/what-vertex-shader-code-should-be-used-for-a-pixel-shader-used-for-simple-2d-spr) for a few tips on using it.

The major advantage of using the XNA stuff in Silverlight 5 is performance. It's hardware accelerated and it's immediate-mode rather than retained-mode. Ideal for game development. (And it can handle 3D.)

The two disadvantages are that there's a smaller install base of Silverlight 5, and not everyone has a video card capable of providing the hardware acceleration that its 3D stuff requires (whereas the retained-mode stuff can at least fall-back to software rendering).

By the way: Drawing in 2D using the 3D API is really pretty simple: Just set up an orthographic matrix, disable Z-buffering, and don't worry about the Z-coordinate.

(Disclaimer: I wrote ExEn, and I'm yet to actually try the Silverlight Toolkit for myself.)

Comment: You talk about needing a capable gfx card,  will they still need that even if I'm using 2D?  Is this the old hardware vs software simulated ?  if so, would the software simulated still be able to handle 2D in this way?  I don't want to exclude people from playing cause of something like this....

Comment: After further inspection, it looks like to get the toolkit example to work, you have to allow Hardware Acceleration in the plugin, otherwise you get a white screen.  My question then is, does everyone get this option, even if they have an integrated graphics card?

Comment: I'm not aware of the exact hardware requirements. I would expect that all modern integrated graphics cards will be able to handle it. My understanding is that only the retained-mode graphics system (the classic Silverlight API, not the XNA stuff) can fall-back to software rendering. However, note that a computer without a suitable GPU probably also lacks a CPU fast enough to do the software rendering at interactive frame rates. Either way you'll probably have to not support those machines - so I'd suggest picking the one that's easiest to program for.